# Converting a data in a table in R to numeric

Tags: r

I am still new to using R and I was hoping someone would be able to help me transform a whole table into a numeric format. 
Originally my data was numeric, but when I used the t() function to flip the rows and columns, the formatting has changed.

My data is [after using t()]:

```
> T_DS
           2016-04-01 2016-05-01 2016-06-01
DS_Mobile       11940       7711       7690
DS_Desktop       8250       7458       5598
DS_Tablet        2680       1953       1739
```

and I need the data to transform without losing the column or row names.

I have tried `data.matrix(T_DS)` and these would change the data.

The code below was the closest I was able to change it, but I would lose the row names and the first column name.

```
T_DS2 <- as.matrix(apply(T_DS[,-1],2,as.numeric))
row.names(T_DS2) <- T_DS[,1]

>       2016-05-01 2016-06-01
11940       7711       7690
8250        7458       5598
2680        1953       1739
```

if you guys have any suggestions, would be immensely helpful!

Thank you

Comment: `t()` will only convert your data away from numeric if there is a `character` entry somewhere, e.g., `x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6); class(c(t(x)))` is `integer`, but if `x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c("a", "b", "c"))`, it will be `character`.

Comment: provide a reproducible example...